# amazon-chime-sdk-js display self video

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, amazon-chime

I created a video application using chime js SDK with the help of the documentation https://aws.github.io/amazon-chime-sdk-js/index.html

```
            const indexMap = {};

            const acquireVideoElement = tileId => {
              for (let i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
                if (indexMap[i] === tileId) {
                  return videoElements[i];
                }
              }
              for (let i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
                if (!indexMap.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                  indexMap[i] = tileId;
                  return videoElements[i];
                }
              }
              throw new Error('no video element is available');
            };

            const releaseVideoElement = tileId => {
              for (let i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
                if (indexMap[i] === tileId) {
                  delete indexMap[i];
                  return;
                }
              }
            };
            const observer = {
              videoTileDidUpdate: tileState => {
                if (!tileState.boundAttendeeId || tileState.localTile || tileState.isContent) {
                  return;
                }

                meetingSession.audioVideo.bindVideoElement(tileState.tileId, acquireVideoElement(tileState.tileId));
              },
                videoTileWasRemoved: tileId => {
                    releaseVideoElement(tileId);
                  }
            };

            meetingSession.audioVideo.addObserver(observer);
            const audioMix = document.getElementById('meeting-audio');
            meetingSession.audioVideo.bindAudioElement(audioMix);
            meetingSession.audioVideo.start();
            meetingSession.audioVideo.startLocalVideoTile();
```

This is working good and I can see all the attendees who is joined in the meeting. But I need to show my video also in a  tag. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In your `videoTileDidUpdate`, for your video tile to show, where are you binding the local tile, I see that if `tileState.localTile` is `true` you are returning and the `bindVideoElement` is not getting called hence your localTile is not showing up. Can you please remove the localTile check and see if that works as the initial step.

Answer (score 0):

```
    videoTileDidUpdate: tileState => {
        // Ignore a tile without attendee ID, a local tile (your video), and a content share.
        const { allUsers } = this.props;
        if (!tileState.boundAttendeeId || tileState.isContent) {
            return;
        }
        if( tileState.localTile ) {
            if( Obj[tileState.boundExternalUserId]['tileId'] === tileState.tileId) {
                return;
            }
        }
        this.meetingSession.current.audioVideo.bindVideoElement( tileState.tileId,document.getElementById(tileState.boundExternalUserId) );
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).